# Pass model to another page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to following models

```
class ModelA < ...
  attr_accessible ...
  has_many :ModelBs

  ...
end
```

For the `new` action i use to following view

`view/modelA/new.html.erb`

```
...
<%= form_for @modelA do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
...
```

in the `create` action i do `redirect_to new_modela_modelb_path` (if success) which is a similar view to create ModelA. The problem is i want only ModelA be created if ModelB is created, i was thinking to pass ModelA to the ModelB view and then create both at the same time. Not sure if this is the proper way to do it and how to do it.

Comment: When you create @modelA, you already have @modelB?

Comment: when i create modelA only A is created then i redirect to create B, to problem is if i cancel it (not submit B at all) modelA is left alone, i want both created at same time

Comment: Why not send the parameters needed for creation of ModelA to the new_modelb action? and the forward the params along with params of B to the create of modelB where model b and a can be created?

Comment: lol, model_a `has_many` model_b, and you want `ModelA be created if ModelB is created`? How was children born when they have no father? And you want to create model B after model A, so why don't you press submit instead of cancel to create model B if you really want to create model B?

Comment: any way, if you want create model B after create model A, or as you means pass model to other page, you can use `redirect_to new_modela_modelb_path(@modelA)` to redirect to new view for create model B after model A was created. And make sure you validated presence for attributes of model B, so you can not submit model B without information :))